# como remover \n de um string em python

Tags: python, string, replace

Estou tentando excluir sequências de controle `(\n, \t, \u)` de strings em Python e não consigo, nem com `replace`, nem com `re.sub()`. Como eu poderia fazer?

Já tentei, e não funcionaram :

```
p = re.sub('\n', '', p)


p.replace("\n","")
```

Comment: Pode colocar o código inteiro? Com `replace` deveria funcionar, então o erro deve estar em outro lugar do código. Você está capturando o retorno do método, `p = p.replace('\n', '')`? Se não, possivelmente esse é o erro.

Answer (score 5):

Com o `replace` é possível, basta atribuir novamente a saída para a variável.

```
minha_string = "teste \n teste"
print(minha_string)
print("==============================")

minha_string = minha_string.replace('\n', '')
print(minha_string)
```

Saída:

```
teste
 teste
==============================
teste  teste
```

Answer (score 1):

Simples, basta usar a função que remove caracteres de controle que estão à direita rstrip(). Então na prática ficaria:

```
SuaString = SuaString.rstrip()
```

Pronto, agora sua string não terá mais os caracteres de controle! ;-)