# Em Python, como excluir os "\n" dos arquivos .txt?

Tags: python, lista, pandas, txt, dataframe

estou no Jupyter Notebook trabalhando com Python.

Estou importando os arquivos em txt com o código a seguir:

```
allLines = []
path = '../data/txt/'
fileList = os.listdir(path)
for i in fileList:
    file = open(os.path.join(path+ i), 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
    allLines.append(file.read().strip())

dados = {
    "nome_arquivo": fileList,
    "texto": allLines
}
raw_data = pd.DataFrame(dados)
raw_data
```

O código acima apresenta o seguinte resultado:

[image: Imagem do Resultado atual]

Os arquivos que estou trabalhando tem as seguintes características:

[image: Imagem do arquivo importado]

Consegui eliminar as quebras iniciasis com o código `.strip()`. Porém, internamente, ainda aparece alguns \n. O resultado esperado é que os arquivos sejam importados sem os "\n" que são as quebras de linhas do txt.

Comment: isso soluciona: `rawdata.texto=[k.replace("\n","") for k in rawdata.texto]`, mas creio que sua pergunat seja duplicada

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [como remover \n de um string em python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/289388/como-remover-n-de-um-string-em-python)

Comment: Obrigado isso funciona, eu já tinha essa solução, pensei que tivesse outra solução dentro do laço. Sobre duplicidade não entendi.

Comment: @Perciliano, que bom que resolveu. Olhe também o método `readlines()`